# Left and Right string detection algorithm and manipulation

Tags: c#, java, regex, string

I'm looking for a mechanism to detect **minimum** and **unique** left and right strings of a given string. Consider the following text:

```
   <button id="allow" type="submit" class="button-big" name="allow" value="93db44648ab3607b10e600eaf796c794" tabindex="4">
```

I need to get value of *value*. So If I decided to choose `substring`, I will use `name="allow" value="` as left string and `"` as right string (based on uniqueness on overall html data)and with their relative index .But a tool which I'm using is detects the unique but minimum enough left string is `w" value="`.

My question is how to find that this? Since I don't have the source of the tools I can't detect it find it.

Please don't suggest me about HAP in C# or any html libraries as the above html code is just an example for easy understanding. I have other kind of data.

Any C# or java snippet would be nice.

Edit:
The data which I'm processing is non html, non standard but team described stuff. And due to the nature it also needs to be coded in Java as well. Hence I can't think about HtmlAgilityPack.

I want to give importance for minimum enough strings rather than all working possibilities to identify the unique pattern.

Comment: why don't you give an example input and output?

Comment: What you mean by sample? I gave that in html form above.

Comment: Seems to me that the minimum left string is *ue="* rather than your started *w" value="*

Comment: What is the input of the algorithm you are looking for supposed to be? Is it the string between the left and right minimum delimiters (e.g. "93db44648ab3607b10e600eaf796c794")? If so, what do you want to do with the found minimum delimiters? You already know the string between them and it is probably hard to guarantee that the minimum delimiters found in one document will also work in another document. I guess you really need to provide more details about the real problem you try to solve and some real examples.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - It's w" value=" because I mentioned that it's necessary due do the whole data string.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you provide an HTML example and some sort of "expected" output, but also say that neither is your example complete nor has it anything to do with the data you want to process... Please describe what exact problem you try to solve, what the inputs are and what you expect as the output. Otherwise, you will get useless answers.

Comment: @SimonLehmann - I'm aware about the problem if the document structure changes. But point is I *want* to find minimum when end user choose auto detect on selected item.

Comment: I looked briefly at that pastebin and while I don't really know what that data is all about, I am sure there are several __usernames and passwords__ for mediafire.com! If this is real data, I'd recommend to remove that quickly!

Answer (score 1):

From your example above, looks like you're trying to parse HTML...

For that I recommend using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead of trying to do it by yourself.

Comment: I clearly stated in my last line, that it's just sample to make it to understand easier. I've different set of data where HAP can't do anything.

Comment: You gave one example, and that solution seems fine for that example, so I recommend you give a better explanation of what exactly is the type of input you are working on

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from your latest comment I try to guess what you want to do and hopefully can give you a pointer in the right direction.

Some user selects some text and says "auto detect minimum delimiters for me". So your input is the whole *text* (of type `String`) and the start and end index of the user's selection (*selectionStart* and *selectionEnd* of type `int`). Your expected output would be two strings that uniquely identify the start and end of the selection in the whole text (let's call them *startDelimiter* and *endDelimiter*), such that

```
text.indexOf(startDelimiter, 0) + startDelimiter.length() == selectionStart
```

and

```
text.indexOf(endDelimiter, selectionStart) - 1 == selectionEnd
```

both hold true.

The general approach for finding a *startDelimiter* would then be to build substrings from *selectionStart - n* to *selectionStart*, starting with *n = 1*, and increase *n* until the first expression above is true. The same can be done for *endDelimiter*, but you would build substrings from *selectionEnd + 1* to *selectionEnd + n + 1* and increase *n* until the second expression is true.

If the delimiters are going to be large, this can get slow. In the worst case, the whole part of the input text preceding *selectionStart* will be the *startDelimiter* and you would only find after *selectionStart - 1* iterations.

Thus, a possible improvement would be to use a binary search approach and double *n* with every iteration until you find a valid delimiter and then proceed to decrease the delimiter in the same way until the substring is not a valid delimiter anymore. The substring before that is your minimum delimiter.

Comment: Just got that idea. I'll apply the code and return the status. Thanks for the concept.